# Android checking for updates to change the progress bar

Tags: java, android

In my app I find how much charge my battery has in percentage. For example when the battery charge changes from 45% to 46%, I want that the changes happens on my app directly without restarting the app. How do I check for changes in battery charge so I can update my progress bar.

What solutions are there in android to make it work. I want to Update the UI when the battery charge changes.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: What is your problem? To make the update in UI or getting the charge value?

Comment: Update the UI when the battery charge changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not really possible, the system won't tell you every change of the battery, which is not practical anyway, you don't want a Broadcast every 0.000001% change of battery level, the system does give you notification when state is LOW or OK .. stuff like that.

If you want to keep a -somewhat- accurate level of battery, you can have a Handler that updates the value every minute or two -for example-, which i think might be a very acceptable level of accuracy for the user.

Edit: some cases you are notified instantly by the system
like ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY, ACTION_BATTERY_LOW, ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED, ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED, and then you can notify the UI immediately

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) is a good reference for the things you can be notified with.

Comment: I want to only make changes on UI when battery status has changed 1%.

Comment: You can't really do that, the closest thing you can do, is update it every interval of time, a minute or a couple of minutes perhaps. The battery is not going to decrease or increase many 1%s in a minute, you can also decrease the time interval if it the phone is charging, stuff like that

Comment: How do I show a direct update in the UI when for example I charge my phone with USB and it shows charging. And when I remove the USB it says discharging. This update must happen immediately.

Comment: How about if I use BroadcastReceiver will that work.

Comment: Yes this is what i meant, BroadCast receivers for the action i mentioned in the answer